# Am I using .then() in the correct way?

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

Like the title says, it's clear based on running authHandler (see below) that it's not doing what I want it to. But I don't know why.

Basically, what I was wanting authHandle to do is first register a new user, generate a userUID and token, and subsequently update the state. Then, once that has been achieved, run the second half of the code to store the new user's user name.

Right now. All it does is registering the user (so initiating the first half of the code) but not executing the second .then() half.

I suspect it's something to do with the states between the first half and second half of authHandler.

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out where I went wrong ><

```
authHandler = () => {
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        const authData = {
            email: this.state.controls.email.value,
            password: this.state.controls.password.value
        };
        this.props.onTryAuth(authData, this.state.authMode); // registers a new user and gives a userUID and token
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.props.onAddUserData(
          this.state.controls.userName.value,
       )
    }) //store the username of the new user
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong, please try again")
    })
};
```

Comment: You don't have a second `.then()`

Comment: Where do you call `resolve/reject `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either `resolve` or `reject` the promise you're creating - right now it's stuck in a pending state so whatever gets called in the `then` of `authHandler()` will never happen. You should also be returning the promise, calling `then` and `catch` where you do won't work properly. this code snippet reorganizes it in a way that should work.

```js
authHandler = () => {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const authData = {
            email: this.state.controls.email.value,
            password: this.state.controls.password.value
        };
        this.props.onTryAuth(authData, this.state.authMode); // registers a new user and gives a userUID and token
        this.props.onAddUserData(this.state.controls.userName.value)
       resolve('done')
    } //store the username of the new user
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong, please try again")
        reject(err)
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys! Much appreciated for the write up @jmcgriz. Yes, the code did sorta work. What I mean by sorta is that when I tried to run the code, it tried to execute onAddUserData first before onTryAuth - which would fail because it needs to happen the other way around, whereby onTryAuth needs to execute first before onAddUserData can (run) ><